# Fluent Validation - Check for Duplicate Value

Tags: c#, blazor, fluentvalidation

I have a EditForm in a Blazor Server application and i want to check if an InputText value is in a list.  How can i pass the list to compare from my UI to the Validator class for comparison?

I have tried comparing the @bind-Value in line and encapsulating the validation message but it skips over the validation message when the encapsulating function tests true.

```
 <EditForm Model="@resourceToBeCreated">
    <FluentValidationValidator ValidatorType=typeof(ResourceValidator)/>
    @if (resourcesSortedCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == resourceToBeCreated.Name) != null)
    {
        <CustomValidationMessage For="() => resourceToBeCreated.Name" /> 
    }
                             
    <InputTextOnInput @bind-Value="@resourceToBeCreated.Name" class="form-control"  placeholder="Name..." />
 </EditForm>
```

I can obviously do this or something similar in the @code section but i dont get the validation popup on inupt.

So the question is, how can i pass this list to the Validator class for comparison?

EDIT 1:
InputTextOnInput component:

```
@inherits InputText
<input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
       class="@CssClass"
       value="@CurrentValue"
       @oninput="EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString)" />
```

EDIT 2:
A potential workaround while still utilising fluent validation.

1, add new property to the model :

```
public List<string> ResourceNames { get; set; }
```

2, when a new resource is created in the browser update that property in the model

```
resourceToBeCreated.ResourceNames = resourcesSortedCollection.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

3, write rule in fluent validation

```
RuleFor(x => x.Name).Null().When(x => x.ResourceNames.Contains(x.Name)).WithMessage("Duplicate resource name");
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it (code smell?) but it works for now.  Either way i have to create a list of strings which contains all the resource names.  If there is a more direct way to pass the resourcesSortedCollection object to the validator id like to understand.

Comment: You can do it in the control.  However, before I answer your question: What is  `InputTextOnInput`? It's not a standard Blazor input control.

Comment: It’s a custom component that inherits from InputText so the value on the input text box binds on key press.  I can post the code, it’s only 2-3 lines long just not at computer right now

Comment: Yes please. post it and I'll answer using it.

Comment: From where `<FluentValidationValidator` comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First an inherited `InputText` control.  This overrides `TryParseValueFromString` and does the validation there.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace BlazorApp1.Pages;

public class InputTextValidated : InputText
{
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public IEnumerable<string>? CheckList { get; set; }
 { get; set; }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, out string? result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string? validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = null;
        validationErrorMessage = null;

        var isValid = this.CheckList is not null
            && this.CheckList.Any(item => item.Equals(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (isValid)
            result = value;
        else
            validationErrorMessage = "You must enter a value in the validation list";

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

And a test page:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<EditForm Model=this.model>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <InputTextValidated class="form-control" CheckList=Countries @bind-Value="@this.model.Country" />
    <ValidationSummary />
</EditForm>

<div>
    Country : @model.Country
</div>

@code {
    private DataModel model = new DataModel();

    private List<string> Countries = new List<string> { "UK", "Spain" };

    public class DataModel
    {
        public string? Country;
    }
}
```

As an alternative you could use/build an Input List control.

#### How Validation works

Validation data is held in `ValidationMessageStore`'s associated with an `EditContext`.  A `ValidationMessageStore` is a composite collection of key/value pairs:

- the field defined as a `FieldIdentifier` [the model as an `object` and the field name as a `string`]
- the validation message as `string`.

Each validation provider has it's own message store and can clear and add messages to it.  It only has write/delete access to it's own message store.  Providers get the `EditContext` cascaded by the `EditForm`, create a message store associated with the `EditContext` and logs messages to and clears messages from that store.  `FluentValidationValidator`, `DataAnnotationsValidator`, any `InputBase` control or classes you write that interact with the `EditContext` are providers with message stores associated with the `EditContext`.

`ValidationSummary` and `ValidationMessage` are consumers.  They interact with the message stores associated with a EditContext via the cascaded `EditContext`.  All the messages are available as read only.  `ValidationMessage` constructs a `FieldIdentifier` from the `For` expression to filter the messages.

Comment: This does work and i never would have through of doing it this way. How does <DataAnnotationsValidator /> know to present the returned string as a validation message?

Comment: @BobbyB - see my "How Validation works" section of the answer.  Once you understand the concepts writing custom validators is relatively easy.  I build mine into my data model.

Comment: Still looking into the fluent validation option.  To use this as is would require significant refactoring of other areas due to implementation of fluent

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to customize Fluent.   Did you look at https://gist.github.com/ShaunCurtis/798a2b6af5f471324fd696f51e0793fe for a totally custom version?  As I often quote "It's all in the design".

Comment: Valuable contribution thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I thought id throw an answer up as i stumbled upon one while doing something else and it may help another.

You can pass the values to validate against into the validator when it is instantiated. In this case pass in a list of BaseResourceMoldes into the ResouceValidator via a constructor.  As the list wont change between instantiation and validation this is suitable.

You then use the Must extension which will pass the parameter you are validating into a called function to test for bool.  In this case .Must(IsUnique) passes x.Name into IsUnique(string arg1) and returns a bool.

Syntax might be slightly different to examples above as the code base will have changed between then and now but the concept is the same.

The class with the form to be validated:

```
[Parameter] public List<BaseResourceModel> Resources { get; set; }
ResourceValidator resourceValidator;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    resourceValidator = new ResourceValidator(Resources);
}
```

And then the ResourceValidator Class:

```
private List<BaseResourceModel> _resources;
private void ResourceValidator(List<BaseResourceModel> resources)
{
    _resources = resources;
    RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().Must(IsUnique).WithMessage("Resource name must be unique");
}

private bool IsUnique(string arg1)
{
    bool isUnique = true;

    foreach (var resource in _resources)
    {
        if (resource.Name == arg1)
        {
            isUnique = false;
        }
    }
    return isUnique;
}
```

I'm assuming you could also do this asynchronously if the list had the potential to change.  Fluent validation has async methods.